# Is there a way to update Xcode project build numbers from jenkins?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, jenkins

I am working on iPhone project where we use Jenkins to generate automatic builds from svn. I am using the below script in build phases to update build numbers from Svn.

REV=`svnversion -nc | /usr/bin/sed -e 's/^[^:]*://;s/[A-Za-z]//'`
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $REV" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}"/${INFOPLIST_PATH}

Its working fine on my working copy but when a build is generated through jenkins its not updating the CFBundleVersion value and it always returns empty.

Any ideas for updating build numbers for the described scenario?

Comment: Try logging into the Jenkins machine that runs your build and run your command to see if you get any useful errors.  Make sure you're logged in as the same user that runs the Jenkins builds.

Comment: its not giving any errors, builds successfully with no warnings. i believe jenkins is not executing run script that i added in build phases of Xcode